# SQL Server : Is it necessary to disable SA user for security issues?

Tags: sql-server, security

We have a website that will published in national grade with millions of users with `Microsoft Sql Server` database.

I need to know is it necessary to disable `SA login` for security issues like DOS attacks ?

Thank you and sorry if question have problems <3.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming or disabling sa account is just part of the story.

There is no drawback if you disable sa account.

It means if you have databases whose owners are sa, there isn't a problem.

System databases like master, or tempDb require that sa be the database owner.

If you try to change the owner of system databases you will receive 15109 error.

Similar situation is with SQL Server Agent jobs, owned by sa. They won't fail, either.

IMO good practice is to have at least one account enabled with sysadmin role.

Comment: Adding that disabling the sa account may be used as part of a overall hardening strategy but is unrelated to the DOS attack called out in the question. DOS/DDOS must be handed at the network level and are not specific to SQL Server.